# If $z_1z_2$ is real and non-zero, then $z_1=p\overline{z_2}$ for some real $p$.

Tags: complex-numbers

> Given that the product of two complex numbers $z_1$ and $z_2$ is real and
>   different from $0$, show that there exists a real number $p$ such that
>   $z_1 = p\overline{z_2}$.

Please help!!

Comment: Use polar coordinates: $z=r e^{i\theta}$.

Comment: No need for polar I think

Comment: Isn't z2bar the complex conjugate of z2? But yeah, i am not really sure where to start?

Answer (score 1):

If $z_{1} z_{2} = r \neq 0$ is real then $z_1, z_2 \neq 0$, and $z_1 z_2= \overline{z_1 z_2} = \overline{z_1} \cdot \overline{z_2} $ and thus:
$$z_1 |z_2|^2 = z_1 z_2 \overline{z_2} = \overline{z_1 z_2} \cdot \overline{z_2} \implies  z_1 = \frac{\overline{z_1 z_2}}{|z_2|^2} \overline{z_2} = \frac{r}{|z_2|^2} \overline{z_2}$$
$\frac{r}{|z_2|^2}$ is a real number and wer'e done.

Comment: Why is z2^2 a real number?

Comment: It is not $z_2^2$, it is $|z_2|^2 = z_2 \cdot \overline{z_2} = \Re({z_2})^2 + \Im({z_2})^2$. Take a $z = a + ib, \overline{z} = a - ib$, multiply them, and see for your self.

Comment: Got it, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

$$z_1 = \frac{z_1 z_2 \bar z_2}{z_2 \bar z_2} = \underbrace{\frac{z_1 z_2}{|z_2|^2}}_p  \ \ \bar z_2$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

$z_{1}\left|z_{2}\right|^{2}=z_{1}\left(z_{2}\bar{z}_{2}\right)=\left(z_{1}z_{2}\right)\bar{z}_{2}$

(So it is enough if $z_2\neq 0$. Then you can divide by $\left|z_{2}\right|^{2}$)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\,\ z_1z_2\in\Bbb R\,\Rightarrow\, z_1z_2 = \bar z_1\bar z_2 \,\Rightarrow \dfrac{z_1}{\bar z_2} = \dfrac{\bar z_1}{z_2} = \overline{\left(\dfrac{z_1}{\bar z_2}\right)}\,\Rightarrow\,\dfrac{z_1}{\bar z_2}\in\Bbb R$